# Flow in the Utility Bar is not refreshing with Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow, aura, utility-bar

I am calling a flow from Utility Bar with Aura Component I am passing recordId but If navigate to other record, RecordId is Changing but flow execution not starting again.If How can I refresh the flow when recordId is changing?

CallFlow.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" /> 

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.recordId}" action="{!c.onRecordIdChange}"/>
    
    <div>
        <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"  />
    </div>
    <h1>{!v.recordId}</h1>
</aura:component>
```

CallFlow.js

```
({
    
    onRecordIdChange:function (component,event){
        var newRecordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log(newRecordId);
        if(newRecordId!=null){
            var flow = component.find("flowData");
            var inputVariables = [
                {
                    name : "recordId",
                    type : "String",
                    value : newRecordId    
                }  
            ];
            flow.startFlow("Test_Flow",inputVariables);
        }
    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this with event="aura:locationChange"

Please refer this link for more details [link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A91fBSAR)